# Trouble with Angular Nested Directives when using ControllerAs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-controller, angularjs-controlleras

I am building a huge form that calls various directives to build a complete form. The Main Page calling the Form Builder passes the ng-model data like this:

```
<div form-builder form-data=“formData”></div>
```

Then the Form Builder Page calls various child directive to build various sections of the Form:

```
FormBuilder.html:

<div form-fields></div>
<div photo-fields></div>
<div video-fields></div>
 .. etc.. etc...
```

When using `$scope` in controller, I had no problem accessing the `$scope` in the child directives like this:

```
function formBuilder() {
    return {
         restrict: 'A',
         replace: true,
         scope: {
            formData: '='
         },
         templateUrl: 'FormBuilder.html',
         controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.formSubmit = function() {
            // Submits the formData.formFields and formData.photoFields
            // to the server
            // The data for these objects are created through 
            // the child directives below
         }
     }
   }
}

function formFields() {
    return {
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: 'FormFields.html',
            controller: function($scope) {
               console.log($scope.formData.formFields);
            }
    }
}

function photoFields() {
    return {
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: 'PhotoFields.html',
            controller: function($scope) {
               console.log($scope.formData.photoFields);
            }
   }
}
... etc..
```

But ever since I got rid of the `$scope` and started using `ControllerAs`, I am having all sorts of trouble accessing 2 way binding with the Parent - Child Controllers.

```
function formBuilder() {
    return {
         restrict: 'A',
         replace: true,
         scope: {
           formData: '='
         },
         templateUrl: 'FormBuilder.html',
         controller: function() {
              var vm = this;
             console.log(vm.formData);  // Its fine here

             vm.formSubmit = function() {
               // I cannot change formData.formFields and formData.photoFields 
               // from Child Directive "Controllers"
            }
        },
        controllerAs: ‘fb’,
        bindToController: true
   }
}

function formFields() {
    return {
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: 'FormFields.html',
            controller: function() {
                var vm = this;
                console.log(vm.formData.formFields); 
                // No way to access 2 way binding with this Object!!!
            }
   }
}

function photoFields() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'PhotoFields.html',
        controller: function() {
            var vm = this;
            console.log(vm.formData.photoFields); 
            // No way to access 2 way binding with this Object!!!
        }
    }
}
```

Whatever I try, I am reaching a road block. Things I have tried are:

1. Isolated Scopes: I tried passing `formData.formFields` and
   `formData.photoFields` as isolated scopes to the child directive,
   but I then end up getting the `$compile: MultiDir` error due to
   nested isolated scopes so it is not possible.
2. If I don’t have
   individual directives for each form section and have all of them in
   1 directive under `formBuilder` directive, then it becomes a
   humungous directive. The above is just a sketch but each child
   directive builds 1 big form put together in the end. So merging them
   together is really the last resort since it does become hard to
   maintain and unreadable.
3. I don’t think there is a way to access
   Parent directive’s `ControllerAs` from Child Directive's `Controller` any other way
   from what I have seen so far.
4. If I use the parent’s ControllerAs in
   the child directive template’s ng-model like `<input type=“text” ng-model=“fb.formData.formFields.text" />`, that works fine, but I
   need to access the same from the Child directive’s controller for
   some processing which I am unable to do.
5. If I get rid of the
   `controllerAs` and use the `$scope` again, it works like before but I am
   trying to get rid of the `$scope` altogether to prepare myself for
   future Angular changes.

Since it is an advanced form, I need to have separate directive to handle various form sections and since nested isolated scopes are not allowed since Angular 1.2, it is making it ever harder especially when trying to get rid of `$scope` using `ControllerAs`.

Can someone guide me what are my options here please? I thank you for reading my long post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need to use `require` option of directive (`require` option is used for communicate directive with directive). Which will give access to its parent controller by just mentioning `require` option in child directive. Also you need to use `bindToController: true` which will basically add isolated scope data to the directive controller.

**Code**

```
function formBuilder() {
    return {
         restrict: 'A',
         replace: true,
         bindToController: true, 
         scope: {
            formData: '='
         },
         templateUrl: 'FormBuilder.html',
         controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.formSubmit = function() {
            // Submits the formData.formFields and formData.photoFields
            // to the server
            // The data for these objects are created through 
            // the child directives below
         }
     }
   }
}
```

Then you need to add `require` option to child directives. Basically the `require` option will have `formBuilder` directive with `^`(indicates `formBuilder` will be there in parent element) like `require: '^formBuilder',`.

By writing a `require` options you can get the controller of that directive in link function 4th parameter.

**Code**

```
function formFields() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        require: '^formBuilder',
        templateUrl: 'FormFields.html',
        //4th parameter is formBuilder controller
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, formBuilderCtrl){
            scope.formBuilderCtrl = formBuilderCtrl;
        },
        controller: function($scope, $timeout) {
            var vm = this;
            //getting the `formData` from `formBuilderCtrl` object
            //added timeout here to run code after link function, means after next digest
            $timeout(function(){
                console.log($scope.formBuilderCtrl.formData.formFields);
            })
        }
    }
}

function photoFields() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        require: '^formBuilder',
        templateUrl: 'PhotoFields.html',
        //4th parameter is formBuilder controller
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, formBuilderCtrl){ 
            scope.formBuilderCtrl = formBuilderCtrl;
        },
        controller: function($scope, $timeout) {
            var vm = this;
            console.log(vm.formData.photoFields);
            //to run the code in next digest cycle, after link function gets called.
            $timeout(function(){
                console.log($scope.formBuilderCtrl.formData.formFields);
            })
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**

One problem with above solution is, in order to get access to the controller of parent directive in directive controller it self, I've did some tricky. 1st include the the `formBuilderCtrl` to the scope variable from link function 4th parameter. Then only you can get access to that controller using `$scope`(which you don't want there). Regarding same issue logged in [**Github with open status**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5893), you could check that out here.

Comment: That is a fantastic solution @pankajParkar. I will try that right away. Thank you so much as I was stuck on this for 3 days trying to figure out a solution! However, I do have a question on `scope` in `link` function. From what I read, Angular 2 will probably be getting rid of `$scope`, so would the above break on Angular 2 since the `scope` is used in `link()`? I understand, its probably too early to prepare for Angular 2, but your thoughts on this as off the rumours today?

Comment: @Neel yes you are correct.. I understood that you are using `controllerAs` pattern come close to angular2 migration.. but there is no solution from my end on that. We need to have scope variable in `controller` & `link` function. there is still open bug on AngularJS issue list https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5893

Comment: Thanks for your input @PankajParkar and +1 for the link. I hope Angular 2 comes up with a elegant way to do this. But for now, your solution will help me. Thanks again. :)

Comment: @Neel angular2 have better implementation for this using DI..if you read up on the link which I've provided to you.. You will come to know many things..